# Text appear below multi table cells after clicking the link.

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a multi-table cells and rows with link inside each and javascript "tdhover", For now every link linked to a new page which is a big number of pages "annoying" I am trying to achieve something like in the screenshot below:

[image: Current table]

My current code is simple html and css:

```
<table style="padding:0px;font-size:10pt;"><tr><td><a href='/path/1/'>1-100</a></td><td><a href='/path/101/'>101-200</a></td> /* .....etc */
```

How can I achieve my goal to appear text below the table each time i click the link and change the previous text with new if i click new link?

Comment: I want to move the content to same page where i have my table, so where i have `<td><a href='/path/1/'>1-100</a></td>` what should i change to make 1-100 clickable and display my text from the `div` below the table? also please keep in mind that i want to hide the previous clicked text if you click new link from the table above and display the new clicked text only and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 day of hard working, searching docs and testing codes, I end up with a solution for my problem.

This is the jquery script to show/hide my divs

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a').click(function () {
var divname= this.name;
$("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
});

});
</script>
```

And here is the html code:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" name="div1" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="div2" >Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="div3" >page2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="div4" >page3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Hello World
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
Test
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none">
Another Test
</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none">
Final Test
</div>


</div>
```

And here is the [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/73LPA/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a DIV below the table where you want to have the text appear.

And using jquery, you can display the text over the DIV on clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

if you have content in same page you can use jquery to display specific text (possibly in an array or switch statement) in a div.

If the content is coming from another page you can use ajax/jquery(.post/.ajax) to achieve this.

Another idea can be defining an iframe(hide at first) where you'll change the source of iframe as you'll click on each link and make it visible

Hope that helps. Please post some code to see y how far you're.

Answer (score 0):

simply create a div where you want the text to appear(below the table). and use the following jquery code:

```
$('#yourtableid a').click(function(){
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
        $('#destination_div_id').html(data);
    })
});
```

This will display the content of linked page in the destination div.

Comment: thank you, you give me the right way to start, please check my answer above.